# Typeclass instance is not resolved after module installed with Cabal

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, cabal

I created simple project to demonstrate the issue: https://github.com/jdevelop/testcabal

If I compile and install the module with 'cabal install', I can not serialize TestData with Binary:

```
> ghci                                               
GHCi, version 7.0.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package ffi-1.0 ... linking ... done.
ghci> :m +TestBinary.Test Data.Binary
ghci> randomData  . decode $ encode emptyTest 

<interactive>:1:24:
    No instance for (Binary TTestData)
      arising from a use of `encode'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Binary TTestData)
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `encode emptyTest'
    In the expression: randomData . decode $ encode emptyTest
    In an equation for `it':
        it = randomData . decode $ encode emptyTest
```

If I load the Test.hs into ghci directly - everything works as expected,

```
> ghci TestBinary/Test.hs 
GHCi, version 7.0.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package ffi-1.0 ... linking ... done.
[1 of 1] Compiling TestBinary.Test  ( TestBinary/Test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: TestBinary.Test.
ghci> randomData  . decode $ encode emptyTest 
Loading package array-0.3.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package bytestring-0.9.1.10 ... linking ... done.
Loading package containers-0.4.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package binary-0.5.1.0 ... linking ... done.
"123456"
```

Version of Haskell compiler:

```
> ghci --version 
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.0.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .cabal file, you have

```
Build-depends: base < 5, ghc-binary >= 0.5, bytestring >= 0.9.1
```

Usually, `ghc-binary` is not exposed, and it is not intended to be used except by GHC itself. When you load `Data.Binary` into ghci, it loads the module from the [`binary`](http://hakage.haskell.org/package/binary) package, and the `Binary` class from that package is a different one than the one from `ghc-binary`, hence `TTestData` has no instance.

If you load the file from source, ghci doesn't care about the .cabal file and uses the class from [`binary`](http://hakage.haskell.org/package/binary) directly, hence it works.

You should change the dependency to the [`binary`](http://hakage.haskell.org/package/binary) package.